# Terraform change nested maps values

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this local map variable
(some AWS ECS tasks definition configurations I read from .JSON files)

```
tasks = {
  "service1" = {
      task_definition = {
        "cpu": 128,
        "environment": [
            {
            "name": "DB_HOST",
            "value": "X"
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "healthCheck": {}
        }
  }
  "service2" = {
    "task_definition" = ...
  }
}
```

I want to change `DB_HOST` value based on other module output :

- worth noting `DB_HOST` won’t appear on each service - should be changed/added

Something like that :

```
tasks.x.task_definition.environment[x].value = module.example.db_host
-> DB_HOST = module.example.db_host
```

didn’t manage to do it when looping through the map keys…

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you add the part where you are looping through the map keys? Additionally, did I understand that what you want to achieve is changing the variable value based on an output value of a module?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'll try to find the code and add it to the original question